# asp.net mvc confirm password always fails

Tags: asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer

I'm using VS2017 Community. Also forgot to mention, This happens in IE11 and not in Chrome.
I generate the default template for an MVC application with Individual user accounts. I hit F5, goto Register, fill in the fields but every time, no matter what, the form does not post and I get the error from the model validations (The password and confirmation password do not match.). As a refresher:

```
 [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
```

I have tried several emails and passwords. I confirmed that I followed the rules in IdentityConfig.cs for the password.

```
// Configure validation logic for passwords
        manager.PasswordValidator = new PasswordValidator
        {
            RequiredLength = 6,
            RequireNonLetterOrDigit = true,
            RequireDigit = true,
            RequireLowercase = true,
            RequireUppercase = true,
        };
```

I'm following a [Pluralsight course](https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/aspdotnet-mvc5-fundamentals) and they do exactly what I'm doing without errors, except he seems to be using an older version of Visual Studio.
 I've searched for this problem six ways to sunday and everything that comes refers to older implementations of MVC where the Compare attribute wasnt fully implemented yet or was implemented differently. 
Can anyone else confirm/deny this works out of the box for them?

And heres the post action, again all default, all template code.

```
 [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent:false, rememberBrowser:false);

                // For more information on how to enable account confirmation and password reset please visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=320771
                // Send an email with this link
                // string code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);
                // var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
                // await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Confirm your account", "Please confirm your account by clicking <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>");

                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            AddErrors(result);
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

Just for grins, heres the default view it generates.

```
@model PSMVCAuth.Models.RegisterViewModel
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Register";
 }

<h2>@ViewBag.Title.</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { @class 
= "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
<h4>Create a new account.</h4>
<hr />
@Html.ValidationSummary("", new { @class = "text-danger" })
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" 
   })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-
label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "form-
control" })
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Register" />
    </div>
</div>
}

@section Scripts {
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
```

}

Comment: Actually, there was something I forgot to try. Debugging, we get to the POST part of the register action for the accountcontroller, and looking at the actual values, I see the ConfirmPassword property has a "\0" appended to the end. I dont understand where this is coming from.

Comment: can you show your controller's post action?

Comment: Did some more digging around. This happens even in production (in Azure). Additionally, according to Fiddler, the passwords ARE the same.